# Warning in Google structured data: either price or review or availability needs to be present

Tags: google, google-search-console, structured-data

I am using the [Google structured data testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) to validate a site. All seems to work fine however I have not been able to solve the following warning (although availability is clearly present)

> Warning: In order to generate a preview with rich snippets, either
>   price or review or availability needs to be present.

A typical url that triggers the warning: https://cartridgeshop.nu/en/hp-364xl-zwart-cn684ee/

Am I missing the obvious?

Source:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="product-wrapper padding_10px margin_bottom_20px" itemscope=""
             itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Product">
            <div class="padding_10px">
                <div class="row-fluid margin_bottom_20px">
                    <div class="span4">
                        <div><img
                                src="https://cartridgeshop.nu/media/cache/shop/product/364xl-zwart-cn684ee/364xlzwart_1_thumbnail.jpg"
                                style=""></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span8">
                        <meta itemprop="category"
                              content="Electronics &gt; Print, Copy, Scan &amp; Fax Accessories &gt; Printer Accessories &gt; Printer Consumables">
                        <h1 class="enhanced"><span itemprop="brand">Hewlett Packard</span>&nbsp;<span itemprop="name">364XL</span>
                            Zwart</h1><a class="small" href="/admin/shop/product/53/">Bewerk product</a>

                        <p class="small margin_top_10px"><span itemprop="description">Origineel HP 364XL inktpatroon. Met HP inktcartridges print je gemakkelijk en voordelig. Snel en gemakkelijk cartridges plaatsen: unieke kleurcodering zorgt dat de juiste cartridge op de juiste plaats komt. Goedkope HP cartridges bestellen doe je bij cartridgeshop.nu!</span>
                        </p>

                        <p class="small margin_top_10px" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">Wij raden u aan te kiezen
                            voor onze compatible Hewlett Packard cartridges. Met onze goedkope cartridge bespaar je op
                            de inkt kosten met behoud van kwaliteit.</p></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <table class="table small">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th style="width:178px">Origineel</th>
                                <th style="width:178px">Huismerk <span
                                        style="color:red;font-weight:bold;display:inline-block;margin-left:4px;">Bespaar 49%</span>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>prijs incl. 21% BTW</td>
                                <td>
                                    <meta itemprop="currency" content="EUR">
                                    <meta itemprop="condition" content="new">
                                    <h3 class="enhanced margin_bottom_10px">€ <span itemprop="price">16,50</span></h3>

                                    <div class="input-append"><input
                                            style="margin-bottom:1px;width:24px;text-align:center;font-size:1.052em;"
                                            type="text" value="1"><a
                                            onclick="addToCart(53, $(this).parent().find('input').val())"
                                            class="btn btn-primary btn-small"><i
                                            class="icon-white icon-shopping-cart-add"></i> bestel</a></div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="success"><h3 class="enhanced margin_bottom_10px">€ 16,68</h3>

                                    <div class="input-append"><input
                                            style="margin-bottom:1px;width:24px;text-align:center;font-size:1.052em;"
                                            type="text" value="1"><a
                                            onclick="addToCart(326, $(this).parent().find('input').val())"
                                            class="btn btn-success btn-small"><i
                                            class="icon-white icon-shopping-cart-add"></i> bestel</a></div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>pagina's</td>
                                <td>550p</td>
                                <td class="success">-</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>milliliter</td>
                                <td>13ml</td>
                                <td class="success"><strong style="color:red;">25,6ml</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>foto's (10x15)</td>
                                <td>-</td>
                                <td class="success">-</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>code</td>
                                <td><span itemprop="identifier" content="sku:CN684EE">CN684EE</span></td>
                                <td class="success">CN684EEC</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>kleur</td>
                                <td colspan="2"><img src="https://cartridgeshop.nu/static/shop/img/colors/1.png"> Zwart
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>geschikte printers</td>
                                <td colspan="2"><p class="small"><a href="/shop/printers/hp/deskjet/3070a/">Deskjet
                                    3070A</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/deskjet/3520e-aio/">Deskjet 3520e AiO</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/officejet/4620/">Officejet 4620</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/officejet/4622/">Officejet 4622</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/5510-2/">Photosmart 5510</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/5515-2/">Photosmart 5515</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/5520/">Photosmart 5520</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/6510/">Photosmart 6510</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/6520-2/">Photosmart 6520</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/7510/">Photosmart 7510</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/7520/">Photosmart 7520</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/b010a/">Photosmart B010a</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/b109adfn/">Photosmart B109a/d/f/n</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/b110ace/">Photosmart B110a/c/e</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/b8550/">Photosmart B8550</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/c5324/">Photosmart C5324</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/c5380/">Photosmart C5380</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/c6324/">Photosmart C6324</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/c6380/">Photosmart C6380</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart/d5460/">Photosmart D5460</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart-estation/c510a/">Photosmart eStation C510a</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart-plus/b209ac/">Photosmart Plus B209a/c</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart-plus/b210ac/">Photosmart Plus B210a/c</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart-premium/c309ang/">Photosmart Premium
                                        C309a/n/g</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart-premium/c310a/">Photosmart Premium C310a</a>,

                                    <a href="/shop/printers/hp/photosmart-premium/c410b/">Photosmart Premium C410b</a>
                                </p></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <span class="small"><strong>Disclaimer</strong><br>De werkelijke opbrengst en/of besparing varieert afhankelijk van de gebruikte printer, de geprinte foto's en andere factoren.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you quote the structured data code in your question.

Comment: Does it work in other page of the same type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under [Product](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en#product_properties), you were missing `offerDetails` in the following line, which nests [Offer](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en#offer_properties):

```
<div class="row-fluid" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
```

Hence, the item in the Offer wasn't nested under Product so the price wasn't found, and an error was being displayed regarding the `price` not being present, as can be seen [here](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004e7999518fd4d42a30d8bea9b8c16) (providing Google retains the test).

So changing that to the following will correct the error:

```
<div class="row-fluid" itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope="" itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
```

As can be seen [here](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=uploaded:8004e79996fe100e9de2383988cb17c6) (providing Google retains the test).

You might find it helpful to compare your code with the example [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en) under `Singe product page`.

Comment: Great, thanks! I really overlooked that, I'll be able to reward your answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be in this part of your code:

```
<span class="small" itemprop="availability" content="in_stock"><span itemprop="identifier" content="sku:CN684EE">CN684EE</span> (in stock)</span>
```

I believe that the "in stock" text must follow the `itemprop` availability code, whereas yours does not.  I couldn't copy and paste the code to check it myself, but try it and see if that fixes the problem.  If not, please copy and paste the code in question, as Dan mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Although Dan's answer above is correct in your case...
I had the same error message when I output **product price's to 4 decimal places (instead of 2)**, and [Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) would skip the price and then give me the same warning message.