# Google stating price is missing from product rich snippet, but it is present

Tags: google-search-console, rich-snippets

I'm trying to figure out how to start adding rich snippets to products but I keep getting an error from Google stating:

> In order to generate a preview with rich snippets, either price or
>   review or availability needs to be present.

But I have price in there in a meta tag. I don't get what's wrong here:

```
<li itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Product" class="span3">
    <div class="thumbnail"><meta itemprop="category" content="flowers">
        <a itemprop="url" href="/en/2-in-too-deep.html" title="Depth">
            <img itemprop="image" alt="A dozen red roses is as romantic as it is classic." src="/2-441-catalog/.jpg">
            <meta itemprop="description" content="[A dozen red roses is as romantic as it is classic.]">
        </a>
        <div class="caption_mobile visible-phone"><p itemprop="name">Depth</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="caption hidden-phone">
        <h4 itemprop="alternateName">Depth</h4>
        <meta itemprop="price" content="&#36;40">
        <meta itemprop="currency" content="USD" />
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Any reason major reason you've opted to use data-vocabulary when since June 2011, several major search engines have been collaborating on a new common data vocabulary called http://schema.org ?

Comment: I had originally tried using schema.org but when I tested it Google displaced 4 errors.  So, without knowing, I tried data-vocabulary and only got one error.

Comment: Sounds like you avoided a problem when you should of fixed it :P

Answer (score 1):

For one, [Offer](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en#offer_properties) should be nested under [Product](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en#product_properties), and `OfferDetails` should have this value for `itemtype`:

```
itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer"
```

Second, [price](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en#offer_properties) should be specified with a `floating point number`.

See the documentation from Google [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750?hl=en) and follow the `Singe product page` code under "Examples" there.

A related question and answer are [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/53486/warning-in-google-structured-data-either-price-or-review-or-availability-needs).